# Split a very large panda dataframe in smaller ones efficiently knowing the large one is ordered

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading in a very large (15M lines) csv file into a panda dataframe. I then want to split it in smaller ones (ultimately creating smaller csv files, or a panda panel...).
I have working code but it's VERY slow. I believe it's not taking advantage of the fact that my dataframe is 'ordered'.

The df looks like:

```
         ticker        date   open     high      low   
0          AAPL  1999-11-18  45.50  50.0000  40.0000   
1          AAPL  1999-11-19  42.94  43.0000  39.8100     
2          AAPL  1999-11-22  41.31  44.0000  40.0600  
...

1000       MSFT  1999-11-18  45.50  50.0000  40.0000    
1001       MSFT  1999-11-19  42.94  43.0000  39.8100    
1002       MSFT  1999-11-22  41.31  44.0000  40.0600  
...

7663       IBM  1999-11-18  45.50  50.0000  40.0000  
7664       IBM  1999-11-19  42.94  43.0000  39.8100   
7665       IBM  1999-11-22  41.31  44.0000  40.0600
```

I want to take all rows where symbol=='AAPL', and make a dataframe with it. Then all rows where symbol=='MSFT', and so on. The number of rows for each symbol is NOT the same, and the code has to adapt. I might load in a new 'large' csv where everything is different.

This is what I came up with:

```
#Read database
alldata = pd.read_csv('./alldata.csv')

#get a list of all unique ticker present in the database
alltickers = alldata.iloc[:,0].unique();

#write data of each ticker in its own csv file
for ticker in alltickers:
    print('Creating csv for '+ticker)
    #get data for current ticker
    tickerdata = alldata.loc[alldata['ticker'] == ticker]

    #remove column with ticker symbol (will be the file name) and reindex as
    #we're grabbing from somwhere in a large dataframe
    tickerdata = tickerdata.iloc[:,1:13].reset_index(drop=True)
    #write csv
    tickerdata.to_csv('./split/'+ticker+'.csv')
```

this takes forever to run. I thought it was the file I/O, but I commented the write csv part in the for loop, and I see that this line is the problem:

```
tickerdata = alldata.loc[alldata['ticker'] == ticker]
```

I wonder if pandas is looking in the WHOLE dataframe every single time. I do know that the dataframe is in order of ticker. Is there a way to leverage that?

Thank you very much!
Dave

Comment: Yes, of course. You are using boolean indexing, how else could it work?

Comment: Your file is uniquely indexed by `(ticker,date)`. You could and should actually **set the index to something meaningful when you read in the file with [`pd.read_csv(..., index_col=...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)**. Either `index_col='ticker'`, or `'date'`, or `['ticker','date']`. Then you can simply use the [`df.filter(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) command to filter rows of interest from the index.

Comment: *"knowing the large one is ordered"* is called *using the index*. Or at least, since your data has a structure, you should actually set an index that reflects that, unlike what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do this is to create a dictionary of the dataframes using a dictionary comprehension and pandas `groupby`

```
dodf = {ticker: sub_df for ticker, sub_df in alldata.groupby('ticker')}
```

---

```
dodf['IBM']

     ticker        date   open  high    low
7663    IBM  1999-11-18  45.50  50.0  40.00
7664    IBM  1999-11-19  42.94  43.0  39.81
7665    IBM  1999-11-22  41.31  44.0  40.06
```

Comment: I'm happy to leave this here because I think it addresses what a majority of questions will be when gravitating here via the title.  But @juanpa.arrivillaga answers the question more appropriately.

Comment: Then... [David Z's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41644421/2336654) answer is also very good.  Sometimes we forget that other tools might be more appropriate.

Comment: This is actually very useful as I might just keep all the data loaded in my program instead of reading in individual csv as needed - depending on memory usage. This is a very clean way to get there!

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense that creating a boolean index of length 15 million, and doing it repeatedly, is going to take a little while. Honestly, for splitting the file into subfiles, I think Pandas is the wrong tool for the job. I'd just use a simple loop to iterate over the lines in the input file, writing them to the appropriate output file as they come. This doesn't even have to load the whole file at once, so it will be fairly fast.

```
import itertools as it
tickers = set()
with open('./alldata.csv') as f:
    headers = next(f)
    for ticker, lines in it.groupby(f, lambda s: s.split(',', 1)[0]):
        with open('./split/{}.csv'.format(ticker), 'a') as w:
            if ticker not in tickers:
                w.writelines([headers])
                tickers.add(ticker)
            w.writelines(lines)
```

Then you can load each individual split file using `pd.read_csv()` and turn that into its own `DataFrame`.

If you *know* that the file is ordered by ticker, then you can skip everything involving the set `tickers` (which tracks which tickers have already been encountered). But that's a fairly cheap check.

Comment: That was my last vote for the day... and I think it was worth it ;-)

Comment: Nice solution. I wonder how this scales vs loading the whole DataFrame into memory. I know `pd.read_csv` and `pd.to_csv` are *very* fast, likewise with `pd.group_by`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, but this has asymptotically better performance than Pandas for very large files because it should only use memory proportional to the number of rows with the same ticker, not proportional to the size of the entire file, so it doesn't incur performance penalties associated with large memory allocations. I'm not sure where the cutoff is at which this becomes better than Pandas, but if 15M lines is slow with Pandas, that _might_ be over the cutoff. It depends on hardware of course; no way to know without some test results.

Comment: @DavidZ Oh sure, I memory-wise your approach is vastly superior. In terms of performance penalties, I regularly load 20million+ row csv files using `pandas` and it's rather quick. The in-memory manipulation is quite fast, too. I wonder where the sweet-spot lies.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I would think it's probably when you get close to maxing out the available memory on the system. As you say, 15M rows is not up that high, so I was a little surprised to hear that the OP is having performance trouble with it, but who am I to argue with results ;-)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but get this error:

`for ticker, lines in it.groupby(lambda s: s.split(',', 1)[0], f):
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

I'm trying to compare all solutions presented so far but can't get this one to work.

Comment: @user1687185 Sorry, I mixed up the order of the two arguments to `groupby()`. I didn't have a chance to test it so I didn't catch the mistake at first. I've edited to fix that.

Comment: Thanks this works. This method is by far the fastest: takes about 4 min total. The other methods using pandas/dictionary/groupby are all similar, take about 30 min to complete. However, if I end up keeping the data in memory instead of having individual .csv to load when needed, a dictionary is a clean datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the best approach is to use `groupby`. Suppose:

```
>>> df
  ticker  v1        v2
0      A   6  0.655625
1      A   2  0.573070
2      A   7  0.549985
3      B  32  0.155053
4      B  10  0.438095
5      B  26  0.310344
6      C  23  0.558831
7      C  15  0.930617
8      C  32  0.276483
```

Then group:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby('ticker', as_index=False)
```

Finally, iterate over your groups:

```
>>> for g, df_g in grouped:
...   print('creating csv for ', g)
...   print(df_g.to_csv())
...
creating csv for  A
,ticker,v1,v2
0,A,6,0.6556248347252436
1,A,2,0.5730698850517599
2,A,7,0.5499849530664374

creating csv for  B
,ticker,v1,v2
3,B,32,0.15505313728451087
4,B,10,0.43809490694469133
5,B,26,0.31034386153099336

creating csv for  C
,ticker,v1,v2
6,C,23,0.5588311692150466
7,C,15,0.930617426953476
8,C,32,0.2764826801584902
```

Of course, here I am printing a `csv`, but you can do whatever you want.

Comment: If your goal is to write csv files, this feels correct.

Comment: @piRSquared I interpreted the OP as ultimately wanting to write csv's. But essentially, we have the same answer: the crux is to use `groupby`.

Comment: Yeah but my answer was a knee jerk response, you read it more carefully.  What I have looks pretty, but functionally what's the point of storing it in a dictionary if you ultimately need in a csv.

Answer (score 0):

Using groupby is great, but it does not take advantage of the fact that the data is presorted and so will likely have more overhead compared to a solution that does. For a large dataset, this could be a noticeable slowdown.

Here is a method which is optimized for the sorted case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

alldata = pd.read_csv("tickers.csv")

tickers = np.array(alldata.ticker)

# use numpy to compute change points, should
# be super fast and yield performance boost over groupby:

change_points = np.where(
    tickers[1:] != tickers[:-1])[0].tolist()

# add last point in as well to get last ticker block
change_points += [tickers.size - 1]

prev_idx = 0

for idx in change_points:
    ticker = alldata.ticker[idx]
    print('Creating csv for ' + ticker)
    # get data for current ticker
    tickerdata = alldata.iloc[prev_idx: idx + 1]
    tickerdata = tickerdata.iloc[:, 1:13].reset_index(drop=True)
    tickerdata.to_csv('./split/' + ticker + '.csv')
    prev_idx = idx + 1
```